# calling a variable from php file in html form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am learning Php through [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) and in `PHP` - Required Fields part the `W3` used  `PHP_SELF` but I wanna try another way (not PHP_SELF) in which I created the form in a html file and write the php code in another `.php` file.

Now to display the errors for required parts in form I faced problem. I don't know how to call the `$nameErr` variable from `php in html form` . my code is as below. 
I want to call Err variable in html form . I tried include but does not work.!

**`train.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="error">* required filed.</span></p>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">*</span> <!-- I want to show "Name is required" here-->
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><span class="error">* </span>   <br><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="website"><span class="error">* </span><br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><span  class="error">* </span><br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
<span class="error">* </span> <br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
 <html>
 <body>

<?php
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website ="";
$nameErr =  $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST") {
if(empty($_POST["name"])){
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
}else{
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["$email"])){
    $emailErr="Email is required";
}else{
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["$website"])){
    $websiteErr = "";
}else{
$website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["comment"])){
    $comment="";
}else{
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
    $genderErr="Gender is required";
}else{
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
}
function test_input($data){
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}


echo "<h2> Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo"<br>";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo $email;    
}
echo"<br>";
echo $website;
echo"<br>";
echo $comment;
echo"<br>";
 echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want to add php code to your form, you will have to use javascript to do the check.

Comment: you cannot call php variable in html file, but you have to write html in php file where you will be able to access php variables or otherwise use ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you **just want to seprate validation and form,**

you can use sessions/cookie to keep validations errors(maybe an array) and just print them in html using php, for example :

train.html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female-
<?php echo $_SESSION['gender_error']; //you need also check if any error exists here! ?>
```

test.php

```
<?php //head of file
    session_start();
    ...
    if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
        $_SESSION['gender_error']="Gender is required";
    }
    ...
    if(/*error happend */) //redirect user to the form(you can search for these things)
?>
```

if you **want to completely seprate PHP Code and HTML**

Then you need a middle language to talk with PHP, as HTML is just a markup language and can't understand any logic by itself.

For example you can use Ajax and Javascript.
take a look at documentation and tutorials on the web to implement this.

if you **want to seprate PHP code and HTML and do not want to use JS**

Then you can use php as a wrapper for you html, define some special tags for yourself, read html file with another php code and replace your special tags with errors or empty string,

There is a lot of tutorials for this option too.